# Python function hangs for large numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that calculate the modular exponential `MODEXP(a,e,p)`.

This function takes `m` and `n` as a parameters, where `p` is a prime number at most `2^m` and `e` is `2^n` and `a` is random number less than `p`.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def question_3(m,n):
    list = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(2,2**m):
        flag=True
        for num in list:
            if(i%num==0):
                flag=False
        if flag:
            list.append(i)
            p = choice(list)
            a = randint(1,int(p)-1) 
            e = pow(2,n)
    return pow(a, e, p)

question_3(5,5)
```

For `m` and `n` over 20, the code begins to hang. How do I prevent that?

Comment: You have a for loop that needs to run over a million times. How fast did you want that?

Comment: i want when entering for example m and n equals to 500 it will work also i want it to take only few ms

Comment: Well, you'll need to come up with an algorithm that doesn't involve building a list of 2^500 integers and then iterate over it to do that fast.

Comment: then, how can i do that ? :)

Comment: To make that clear: Your algorithms does about 2^m steps. Even if a single step took a picosecond (it doesn't), your algorithm would take **10^131 years** for m=500. You need a radically different approach.

Comment: By "modular exponential", do you mean the modular exponentiation a^e modulo m? If so, it's just `pow(a,e,m)`. If not, please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: guys i am beginner also i tried alot but i failed thats why i posted it here :)

Comment: are you calling your function recursively? (for no reason)
or is it indentation problem

Comment: @noazetabdo You need to state what you want to achieve, not just the problem with the code.

Comment: @adil it is a recursive function but i think the problem is using large number for example by entering m=500 it will loop over 2^500 but i don't know how to prevent that

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil what i want to calculate the function with entering large numbers without hanging

Comment: We can't tell you how to make it faster because you are not answering questions about what the function is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to calculate 
(modulus of `a` raised to the power `e`)mod`p`
 or something similar then

I would Highly recommend you this wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method)

In this case maximum number of iteration would be equal to number of bits in binary representation of variable `e`.

Comment: No need to read an article, in Python it's simply `pow(a,e,p)`. But OP is already using that so I have no idea what they are actually trying to do.

Comment: well I posted that because as the OP is bit unclear So he can read the article and use it in his own implementation.(This may help)
And reading something and then using it is much better than using `pow(a,e,p)` blindly.

Comment: No, reinventing the wheel is not better than using an existing built-in solution. And in any case, this doesn't seem to be what OP needs -- the first sentence in the question seems to be misleading.

Comment: @interjay what the function supposed to do is to calculate pow(a,e,p) where p is prime generator at most 2^m and e=2^n and a is random number less than p ... also by entering any value of m and n it should work efficiently without hanging ... that's all

Comment: @interjay Kind off getting your point here.... But I was not trying to convey a message like "plz reinvent something".